# print (arr[1]), TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-2.7

I am compiling the following python code getting error print (arr[1]), TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable. Please help me to resolve this.

```
t = int(input())
while t!=0:
    n,k = map(int, input().split())
    arr = map(int, input().split())
    index = n - k
    for i in range(index, n):
        print arr[1],
    for i in range(index):
        print(arr[i]),
    print (" ")
    t-=1
```

Comment: You need to turn your `map` into a `list`. `arr = list(arr)`.

Comment: Your code is in python-2.7, not in python-3.x. Please update the tag. The behavior of `map` is different in 2.7 and 3.x. Apparently, you attempted to execute your code with a 3.x interpreter, and that's why you get the error.

Comment: Yes I have python 2.7.6 tried to turn map into as you stated is quite confusing me . Could you please make changes is my code and post. Thank You

Comment: Your code is syntactically correct, but you must run it in python 2.7, not 3.x.

Comment: Oh! Yes got passed. Thank You